# What is wrong with these statements?

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem

Explain what is wrong in each of the following statements.

(a) For large sample size n, the distribution of observed values will be approximately Normal.

(b) The 68-95-99.7 rule says that $\bar x$ should be within µ ± 2σ about 95% of the time.

(c) The central limit theorem states that for large n, µ is approximately Normal.

Comment: Is it your homework? What is your thought?

Comment: It might help to look up the central limit theorem and see what it (at least the ["classic" CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT)) actually says

Answer (score 4):

(a) For a large sample size, the distribution of observed values will be approximately the actual underlying distribution of the random process. If they come from a normal distribution, it'll look normal. If they comes from a uniform distribution, it'll look uniform.

(b) According to the 68-95-99.7 rule, the sample average should be within $\mu\pm2\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ about 95% of the time. Note that as $n$, the number of samples, goes up, the sample average is contained in a closer and closer ball to the theoretical average.

(c) The **sample average of $n$ values** will be approximately normally distributed. The sample average, or observed average, is often called $\hat{\mu}$. However, if you knew the actual distribution, then $\mu$, the theoretical average or expectation of the distribution, is a fixed, non-random number that is a property of the distribution.

Comment: Please see the advice on answering this kind of question in the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).